# How to plot large error bars on logarithmic scale in Julia language?

Tags: plot, julia

I need to plot a graph of a power law curve on logarithmic scale with error bar. However, sometimes the error can have a very large amplitude and ends up returning an error "No strict ticks found".
For example:

```
x = 1:10
y = x .^ (-2)  # Power law y = x^(-2)

error_amplitude = 0.5
error = y .* error_amplitude  # Error bar
    
plot(x, y, xaxis=:log, yaxis=:log, ribbon=error, legend=false)
```

This code generates the following graph
[image: Graph]

But if `error_amplitude=1.0`, it returns "No strict ticks found".

It seems to me the error cannot be greater than the average value (amplitude>1), but it is not obvious to me why this happens. Would there be any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It may not make much sense to plot both a variable (when that variable and its error are identical) and its error in log terms, since one edge of the difference becomes 0, and what's the log of 0? The area required on the lower right portion of the plot may become difficult to plot precisely.

You can plot that error without the log on y axis:

```
using Plots

x = 1:10
y = x .^ (-2)  # Power law y = x^(-2)

error_amplitude = 1.0
error = y .* error_amplitude  # Error bar
  
plot(x, y, xaxis=:log, ribbon=error, legend=false)
```

[image: plot of example]

Notice how the y value and its error approach 0 on the right.  The plotting function is saying that it is not equipped for making a tick for -Inf here.